# Prev and Next button is not working correctly at the breakpoints

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-slick

Guys I'm facing a problem in `react-slick` slider. I'm rendering a card on the slider depends upon the array length. I'm also rendering custom `next` and `previous` buttons which triggers the `next` and `previous` functions to change the slide.  I also wanted to this slider to be responsive. It means it has a functionality to scroll the slides according to the defined settings.

**My defined settings for the breakpoints**:

`992` > slidesToScroll = 3

`577 - 991` slidesToScroll = 2

`0 - 576` slidesToScroll = 1

The `next` button will be disabled when there is no forward slide and the `previous` button will be disabled when there is no back slide. To achieve this functionality, there is a function named afterChange that returns the current active index of the slides. So I assign that index on the `state`.
But I think my logic for the `next` button is not correct.

What are my issues?

- Is there any way to `refresh` the slider when the window is resized because the slides are not reset according to the `breakpoints`?
- The `next` button is not disabled at the breakpoint `(0 - 576)` even if there is no slide ahead.
- When the user changes a single slide and then resizes the window
  to move to the next slide, the `Next` button becomes inactive.

I think the problem is in my logic that is written inside `renderArrows` function.

**See this**:

[image: React-slick problem]

Codesandbox: [View this](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-jsk7o-jsk7o)

Code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";

// Constant Variables
// Slides scroll behavior on different sizes
const TOTAL_SLIDES = 6;
const DESKTOP_SLIDES_SCROLL = 3;
const TABLET_SLIDES_SCROLL = 2;
const MOBILE_SLIDES_SCROLL = 1;

/**
 * It will return the JSX and register the callbacks for next and previous slide.
 * @param prevCallback {function} - Go back to the previous slide
 * @param nextCallback {function} - Go to the next slide
 * @param state {object} - Holds the state of your slider indexes
 * @param totalSlides {number} - Holds the total number of slides
 * @return {*} - Returns the JSX
 */
const renderArrows = (
  prevCallback,
  nextCallback,
  { currentIndex, slidesToScroll },
  totalSlides
) => {
  const cycleDots =
    currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(totalSlides / slidesToScroll);
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={currentIndex === 0} onClick={prevCallback}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button disabled={currentIndex > cycleDots} onClick={nextCallback}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  // We just have to keep track of the index by keeping it in the state
  const [state, setState] = useState({ currentIndex: 0, slidesToScroll: 0 });

  // To access underlying DOM object for the slider
  const sliderRef = useRef();

  // Trigger next method to show the next slides
  const next = () => {
    sliderRef.current.slickNext();
  };

  // Trigger previous method to show the previous slides
  const previous = () => {
    sliderRef.current.slickPrev();
  };

  // Slider Settings
  const settings = {
    slidesToShow: 3,
    dots: false,
    draggable: false,
    slidesToScroll: DESKTOP_SLIDES_SCROLL,
    arrows: false,
    speed: 1300,
    autoplay: false,
    centerMode: false,
    infinite: false,
    afterChange: indexOfCurrentSlide => {
      setState({
        currentIndex: indexOfCurrentSlide,
        slidesToScroll: DESKTOP_SLIDES_SCROLL
      });
    },
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 992,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: TABLET_SLIDES_SCROLL,
          afterChange: indexOfCurrentSlide => {
            setState({
              currentIndex: indexOfCurrentSlide,
              slidesToScroll: TABLET_SLIDES_SCROLL
            });
          }
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 576,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: MOBILE_SLIDES_SCROLL,
          afterChange: indexOfCurrentSlide => {
            setState({
              currentIndex: indexOfCurrentSlide,
              slidesToScroll: MOBILE_SLIDES_SCROLL
            });
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div>
        <h1>Slider Buttons</h1>
        {renderArrows(previous, next, state, TOTAL_SLIDES - 1)}
      </div>

      {/*  Slider */}
      <Slider {...settings} ref={slider => (sliderRef.current = slider)}>
        {[...Array(TOTAL_SLIDES)].map((_, index) => {
          return (
            <div className="card" key={index}>
              <div className="card-img-top">
                <svg
                  className="svg"
                  width="100%"
                  height="225"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
                  focusable="false"
                >
                  <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#55595c" />
                  <text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#eceeef" dy=".3em">
                    Image {index + 1}
                  </text>
                </svg>
              </div>
              <div className="card-body">
                <p className="card-text">
                  This is a wider card with supporting text below.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like everything is working already but the disabled `Next` button. I think it should work already by changing the `disabled` condition to check the amount of slides the slider is at.

Changing the `renderArrow` body to this in the provided code sandbox seems like it works:

```
  const lastElementsIndex = totalSlides - slidesToScroll;
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={currentIndex === 0} onClick={prevCallback}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button disabled={currentIndex > lastElementsIndex} onClick={nextCallback}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
```

Since the initial state is not synchronized with the actual values depending on the breakpoint, there might be a special case as pointed out in the comments. Using `onReInit` as a non-arrow function should get access to the `this` object of the Slick slider itself. From there, the correct `slidesToScroll` can be retrieved:

```
const settings = {
  // ... other settings ...
  onReInit: function() {
    const slidesToScroll = this.slidesToScroll;
    if (slidesToScroll !== state.slidesToScroll) {
      setState(state => ({ ...state, slidesToScroll }));
    }
  },
  // ... other settings ...
};
```

In a previous edit, I've proposed using `onInit` - using `onReInit` has the benefit of shooting on window resize as well. Thus it should also synchronize the state correctly when resizing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to ask if `currentIndex = 0`, `totalSlides = 2` and `slidesToScroll = 0`. So in this case `3 slides` have already appeared then `lastElementsIndex` value will be `2`. The next button won't be disabled because our condition will return false i.e. `0 > 2` How will you deal with it?

Comment: When `slidesToScroll = 0` - what does that mean? This sounds to me that the user should not be able to scroll at all / doesn't see any slides at the same time?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you. This is the Codesandbox link [see here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-slick-2-jsk7o-m0e8o) In this example you can see that the total slides in the global variables are `3` and in `Desktop break-point` 3 slides have already appeared and there is no slide ahead. So the next button should have been disabled.

Comment: Ahh okay, now I see the second issue. Sorry! In the linked code, `state` is not synchronized with the state that the slider receives in the beginning. `slidesToScroll` only updates to the correct value when the slider changes and thus updates later. You could use the `onInit` prop to synchronize that. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

I find a problem in {currentIndex > cycleDots}. Please change into {currentIndex >= cycleDots}

Comment: Can you help me ? Do you know any way to refresh the slider when the window is resized?

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is what I did to get your code working:

```
const renderArrows = (
  prevCallback,
  nextCallback,
  { currentIndex, slidesToScroll },
  totalSlides
) => {
  let cycleDots = 0;
  if (slidesToScroll !== 0) {
    cycleDots =
      currentIndex === 0 ? 1 : Math.ceil(totalSlides / slidesToScroll);
  } else {
    cycleDots = 5;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={currentIndex === 0} onClick={prevCallback}>
        Previous
      </button>
      <button disabled={currentIndex >= cycleDots} onClick={nextCallback}>
        Next
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I don't know what you wan't to set the 'cycleDots' value to in the if-else statement; but you should be able to replace the 5 with whatever the totalSlides is minus 1;